# Updating tables with Linq expressions

Tags: linq, datatable

Most of the examples I've found deal with Linq to entities, which is not what I need. I have a standard DataTable which I need to modify before returning to the caller. I can iterate over the normal `Table.Rows` collection or do something like this with the new extension methods:

```
foreach (var x in table.AsEnumerable()) {
    if (x.Field<int>("SomeField") > SomeValue)
        x.SetField<string>("OtherField", "OtherValue");
}
```

But I'm still manually looping through the entire row collection. Not necessarily a big deal, but I'm wondering if there's a more elegant way to accomplish this with Linq somehow, in the sense that I need to create an expression that iterates over the results of a query and performs an arbitrary action, rather than just select elements from the container being enumerated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're wondering is if there's some sort of extension method like

```
stuff.ForEach(x => x.Value = "new value");
```

Unfortunately, there is no such thing. When I began using LINQ to SQL, I wanted the same thing. But unfortunately, you must use a for loop.

Comment: Looks like you get the 'tumbleweed' award, if there's one :D Thanks for the comment... yeah, I pretty much figured there was no way to do that, but my Linq-fu was a bit weaker back then.

Comment: Ha! I just realized this was asked almost a year ago. And MS still hasn't implemented the ForEach method.